# Parse.com - How to pass a nil parameter into cloud code?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm coding for iOS and calling my cloud code function using the iOS SDK. One of my parameters is sometimes nil which causes an error.

I'd like to be able to pass some form of nil and check it in the cloud code function. My Javascript is weak and I'm not sure if this is a JS issue or a Parse cloud code issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[NSNull null]` in the dictionary of parameters that you are passing to the cloud function.

In JavaScript, you should be able to check if a value exists by using either

```
if (request.params.myParam) {} // true if undefined, null, 0, or ""
```

or, if you want to be more specific, use

```
if (request.params.myParam == null) {} // true if undefined or null
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether your question relates to iOS or JS, but assuming you are asking about iOS/Objective-C, you cannot pass nil into a dictionary, as it can only hold objects.  Use

```
[NSNull null]
```